# jquery sort string data

Tags: jquery, string, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I have to sort some data-attribute. Like this :

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content" data-price="50" data-name="DEF">
   </div>
   <div class="content" data-price="10" data-name="ABC">
   </div>
</div>
```

I use this code for sort price, and it's works very well :

```
function sort_by_price(){
    $('.container').each(function(){ //I have more than 1 container
        $(this).find('.content').sort(function(a, b){
          return +a.dataset.price - +b.dataset.price;
        }).appendTo($(this));
    });
}
```

But, I can't use this code for sorting data-name, because is, I think, a string variable. Then do you know how to make that code works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function f (a,b){
    // Getting the lowercase strings to avoid problems with lowercase and uppercase
    a= a.dataset.name.toLowerCase();
    b= b.dataset.name.toLowerCase();

    if(a>b)
        return 1; 
    else
       return a===b?0:-1;
}

function sort_by_name(){
$('.container').each(function(){ //I have more than 1 container
    $(this).find('.content').sort(f).appendTo($(this));
});
```

CODE NOT TESTED. I think this should work. Be careful with lowercase and uppercase